# Help me to solve $\overline{abc} \cdot d +\overline{ef}\cdot g + h \cdot i = 2010$

Tags: combinatorics, dynamic-programming

The problem is:
$$(a \cdot 100 + b \cdot 10 + c ) \cdot d + (10\cdot e + f ) \cdot g + h \cdot i = 2010$$
and
$$\{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i\} = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\}.$$(not allowed to repeat).

For example, $$976 \cdot 2 + 38 \cdot  1 + 4 \cdot  5 = 2010$$

I write a program to enumerate all the solutions. But I want to know how to solve it with math.

Comment: Please use Mathjax

Comment: you can apply dynamic programming to store number of ways a sub-term can give result to a number.

Comment: Also do you want the number of solutions or all the solutions to be listed ?

Comment: @Roby5 not allowed

Comment: This is peter frankl's favorite puzzle.

Comment: $(a,d)=(2,9)(3,6)(6,3)(9,2) $

Comment: I count 68 solutions. I think this is more a programming exercise than a useful or interesting maths problem.

Comment: Writing a program *is* solving it with math. Computer science is a subset of Mathematics.